# Excel: find values in column A but not in column B, return values in column C

Tags: excel-formula

### Find all values which are in column A but not in column B.

> This formula searches across the entire column B for the value in cell
>   A2. If no match is found, the formula returns "No match in B", an
>   empty string otherwise:
>
> `=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B, $A2)=0, "No match in B", "")`

- Instead of **No Match in B** I want the actual value in Column A to
  be listed.  Can the formula be edited to accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your formula in **C2** replace:

"No match in B"

with:

A$2

and copy downward.

Comment: I used $A:$A - Thanks